# Need to find translation based on ID in xml

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml file and I am confused how to find **translation** tag using the **id** tag which lie inside a message element.

What is the easiest way to look in name=menu and print the translation whose id=1

Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TS>
<TS version="2.0" language="en_GB" sourcelanguage="en_GB">                
    <context>
        <name>Menu</name>
        <message>
            <id>1</id>
            <source>Home</source>
            <translation>Home</translation>
        </message>
        <message>
            <id>25</id>
            <source>About</source>
            <translation>About</translation>
        </message>
    </context>
    <context>
        <name>Web</name>
        <message>
            <id>59</id>
            <source>Welcome to </source>
            <translation>Welcome to </translation>
        </message>
        <message>
            <id>68</id>
            <source>Happy</source>
            <translation>Happy</translation>
        </message>
    </context>
</TS>
```

Comment: Find `message` with certain `id`, then get it's children and select `translation`

Answer (score 1):

Use a XML parser for this. In this example, I will use built-in [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) with [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php):

```php
$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadXML( $xml );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );

$nodes = $xpath->query( '//context/message/id[.=25]/../translation' );
echo $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Will print:

> About

`->loadXML( $xml )` loads your XML string, to load a file use `->load( $filePath )` instead.

The xpath syntax allow to performs short, complex queries. Above xpath means:

```
/                    Root element
TS/context/message   Descendant tree
/id[.=25]            tag `<id>` with 25 as node value
/..                  `<id>` parent tag (<message>)
/translation         `<translation>` child
```

With this query we select all nodes with that matches above pattern (one node, in your case); the result is a group of nodes, so to refer to a node we have to use `->item(n)` syntax. To extract its content, we use `->nodeValue`.

In my example I use a complete-tree syntax, but in your XML `<id>` is in unique tree position, so you can short xpath query in this way:

```
//id[.=25]/../translation
```

The `//` at start means “Select following pattern no matter where they are in the document”.